# How do I return a user-specified type on success or a String on failure?

Tags: generics, rust, return-type

I have a program where user input is collected in a function and a value is returned. In the function, it tries to parse the `String` input to a `u32`. If it fails, rather than panic and end the program, I want it to return the `String`.

Is it possible to allow any return type? I read the generics section in the Rust Book, but it didn't include anything about returning a generic type.

Here's my code:

```
fn read_input(question: &str) -> u32 {
    let mut input = String::new();
    println!("{}", question);
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read input");
    match input.trim().parse() {
        Ok(number) => {
            return number; // return a u32
        }
        Err(_) => {
            return input; // return a String
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are asking two distinct questions here.

**1. How can the user specify the output type of a function?**

Use a generic parameter. For example, the [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) requires a type parameter `B`, which is used as return type.

**2. How can I return a value that can be of two distinct types?**

You can create a `enum` that will serve as the "union" of the two types:

```
pub enum Union<A, B> {
    ValueA(A),
    ValueB(B)
}
```

In this case, there is no intrinsic meaning for the `ValueA` or `ValueB` case.

The [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html) enum  is similar to this, but it adds meaning to each case, that is, the `Ok` case indicates success and `Err` indicates an error.

---

That said, I suggest that you use `Result` and that the error case returns the read input with the `parse` error:

```
use std::io;
use std::str::FromStr;

// 1: T is a type parameter that is used as (part of) return type
//
// 2: Result allows you to return either the parsed T value or
//    the read input value with the parse error 
fn read_input<T: FromStr>(question: &str) -> Result<T, (String, T::Err)> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    println!("{}", question);
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read input");
    match input.trim().parse() {
        Ok(p) => Ok(p),
        Err(err) => Err((input, err))
    }
}
```

This will allow you to write a nice error message to the user:

```
fn main() {
    // you can use any type that implements FromStr instead of u32
    match read_input::<u32>("2 + 2?") {
        Ok(ans) => println!("answer: {}", ans),
        Err((input, err)) => println!("\"{}\" is an invalid answer: {}", input, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered my question(s) perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the thing to do for this particular function is return the `Result` from the `input.trim().parse()` line. The method can also be made generic as you say to return the result from anything that is `parse-able` [see docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse)

```
fn read_input<F>(question: &str) -> Result<F, F::Err>
    where F : FromStr 
    {
    let mut input = String::new();
    println!("{}", question);
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("failed to read input");
    input.trim().parse()
}
```

See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd9ab60fa48a208b75575ad6c118a029&version=stable&backtrace=0) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/bd9ab60fa48a208b75575ad6c118a029)

Comment: `ok().expect()` is bad, it throws away the information in the `Result::Err`. Use `.read_line().expect()`.